# How should I get the Ajax response from the servlet?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, servlets

I have an Ajax request coming from client side after a key press. The servlet returns a string.

How should I grab this string on the client side? It should be split on `","` on the client side and display the list. We are using Velocity for rendering the HTML.

Servlet code:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String acInfo = request.getQueryString();
    SomeDAO dao = new SomeDAO();
    ArrayList<String> results = dao.acResults(acInfo);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int count = 0;
    for (String acResult : results) {
        sb.append(acResult);
        count++;
        if (count == results.size()) {
            break;
        }
        sb.append(',');
    }
    out.println(sb);
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: From the Ajax query's result? It depends how you're making the request (hopefully not using raw JavaScript).

Comment: @dave Newton The request that is sent from the ui is a simple string like 'li', i am not framing any query.What do you mean by raw Javascript?

Comment: @DaveNewton we are using jQuery in the front end

Comment: *What* the request is isn't relevant, how it's *made* is. "Raw JavaScript" means no framework.

Comment: What's the issue, then? Show your jQuery code with the success callback.

Comment: @DaveNewton I don't have the Jquery code yet. I am just doing the backend hooking up. We are still developing our own auto complete wizard.  So i was wondering, how this get hooked up with UI. Your Post helped me what the to do's next. Thanks

Comment: Also, besides that Apache Commons already has a `StringUtils.join(",")` method, it should be refactored into its own method (as should most of that `doGet` code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont use "async: false" or it will lose all the AJAX meaning. 
Do all the stuff you want in the success method. To split by ',', just use split() and to easily iterate arrays use $.each()

```
$.ajax({ type: "GET",   
     url: "/YourServletURL",   
     success : function(text)
     {
         var list = text.split(',');
         $.each(list, function(index, value) { 
          alert(index + ': ' + value); 
         });
         // This will show the values. Change "alert" for $('div#mydiv').html(value) or so
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using Jquery then you can use following:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","YOUR_SERVLET_RELATIVE_URL",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>AJAX</h2>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Request data</button>
<div id="myDiv"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a simple jQuery ajax response scenario - can't you handle the response with code of following nature ?

```
var responseText = '';
$.ajax({ type: "GET",   
         url: "/YourServletURL",   
         success : function(text)
         {
             responseText = text;
         }
});

//alert response or process it or display somewhere
alert(responseText);
```

Comment: @pushya Note that this code most likely isn't what you want, since it's asynchronous, and is not the canonical Ajax/jQuery pattern. Using this as an example breeds bad habits.

Comment: @DaveNewton: you perhaps meant to say "since it's synchronous"?

Comment: All, the intention was to show a usage scenario of handling response - @pushya  -do not copy paste the code above for your implementation. Note that I said "code of following nature"